# fabricjs: Issue with multiple paths of SVG having the exact same gradient

Tags: svg, fabricjs

For my web app, I am creating SVG elements in Illustrator and then using them in a library of elements that users can add to the fabric canvas.

Some elements are simple but some complex with multiple compound paths etc.

I have came across an unusual issue where if I create a path with a gradient fill, and then copy that path, save the SVG and add it onto the canvas, only the first path would have the gradient and the rest would be flat colors.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean...

[image]

After experimenting and trying different things, I finally discovered that this is happening because the paths have the exact same gradient properties.

So if the gradient slider (color stops, opacity, location etc.) of two or more paths have the exact same properties in Illustrator, then the issue occurs.

So the workaround is to alter something like the location (for example) to be 99.9% instead of 100% on the copied path, then the issue goes away. However, this will quickly become a tedious and annoying way to fix this. Basically, each path with a gradient, needs to have a unique gradient set up and cannot be identical to another paths gradient properties.

Here are more screenshots to better explain...

[image]

After making this change...

- The first and second path's gradient's location are different.
- The first, third, fourth and fifth paths have exact same gradient.

This is what it looks like when I add it to the canvas now...
[image]

Here is the code I am using to add the SVG to the canvas...

```
  fabric.loadSVGFromURL(image, function(objects, options) {

      var oImg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

      oImg.perPixelTargetFind = true;
      oImg.targetFindTolerance = 4;
      canvas.add(oImg);
      canvas.renderAll();

  });
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and if there is a way to fix this with code rather than Illustrator? I have hundreds of elements to create that will have many paths with the same gradients. I know it will be a real pain to have to worry about paths not having the exact same gradient.

http://jsfiddle.net/oc70xjsq/

[Link to the SVG](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohpkmxel6vwa6li/mysvg.svg?dl=0)

Comment: Can you upload that svg and create a snippet/fiddle using that?

Comment: Ok, I have created a fiddle but in the fiddle, I am loading the SVG from a string instead of fromURL because I was having CORS issues. Should be the same result.

Comment: Update your fabricjs, its fixed already. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/xhr2m36t/)

Comment: This particular bug was fixed with release 2.4.4. If you have a specific reason for not updating to v2 you can always try to backport the PR. https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/pull/5408/files

Comment: Ok I updated to v2.4.6 and it is fixed. Thanks.